# squaring the circle: turning a circle into a square.

Tags: geometry, pi, transcendental-numbers

I've heard of the ancient problem of squaring the circle, whereas a circle is made into a square. I've heard that since $\pi$ is **NOT** rational (and a transcendental) number, it is not construct-able. my question is, is there a close estimate that will be close to $\pi$? as in:

$$ f(x)\sim \pi$$

Comment: Since rationals are both constructible and dense in $\mathbb R$, the answer is yes.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Every rational number is constructible so just take any rational number near $\pi$.

Comment: Do you like $$\pi = 2+2\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2^n}{(n+1)n^2\binom{2n}{n}} $$ ?

Comment: How close do you want to get? Do you mean something like this? $ \frac{ \lfloor(10^n*pi) \rfloor }{10^n} $

Comment: If you have a method of computing arbitrarily many digits in the decimal expression $\pi = 3.14159265358979...$ then for any integer $n \ge 1$ you get an estimate accurate to within $10^{-n}$ by rounding off at the $n^{\text{th}}$ digit after the decimal point.

Comment: You also might want to look more closely at the definition of a constructible number, it may not mean what you think it means. For example, $\sqrt{2}$ is constructible, despite being not rational. And $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not constructible, despite being non-transcendental.

Comment: There are [several hundred Questions previously asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=approximating+pi+is%3Aquestion) here about approximating $\pi$.  While some of them may be at too advanced a level for your studies, you would benefit from looking through them to see if some clarity in formulating your own Question can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, essentially you'd want to take the partial continued fraction expansions of $\pi$ and continually construct squares of that side length. There are lots of ways to use continued fractions to do this, my favorite is the following;

$$ \pi = \cfrac{4}{1+\cfrac{1^2}{3+\cfrac{2^2}{5+\cfrac{3^2}{7+\cfrac{4^2}{9+\ddots}}}}} $$